# string to int cast php change value

Tags: php

```
$ms = microtime(true);
$ts = $ms * 10;
$i = substr($ts, 0,strpos($ts, "."));
echo "    A: ". $ms;
echo "    B: ". $ts;

echo "    C: ". $i; 
echo "    D: ". intval($i); 
echo "    E: ". (int)$i;
```

example:

> A: 1382292940.8799
>   B: 13822929408.799
>   C: 13822929408
>   D: 2147483647
>   E: 2147483647

But

> E =/= C &&  D =/= C

Why does this happen?

Comment: `2147483647` is the highest number PHP can store in a 32 bit integer! See here: http://php.net/manual/language.types.integer.php

Comment: Are you running a 32 bit server? I tested your code on http://writecodeonline.com/php/ and it gives the results you expected.

Answer (score 4):

The problem you are having is an overflow one. 32-bit integers hold up to 4 billion and some unsigned and only 2 billion and some signed. The number you are converting to an integer is much larger than that:

```
13,822,929,408
```

Hence you are seeing 2147483647, the limit for a 32-bit signed integer.

Comment: And the reason `$ts` displays properly is that PHP is calculating/storing it as a double-precision floating point number.